# php_memcached compiling in windows

Tags: php, windows, memcached, php-extension

I'm trying to build php_memcached.dll in order to interface my server with memcached service.
I followed this tutorial https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild and downloaded the last version of memcached from here https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached but when I try to call

```
configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-memcached
```

The configure procedure fails because it doesn't find memcached.lib file.

I'm trying to compile against php-5.6.8 source code, for x86 with vc11. I use “VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt”.

Answer (score 0):

libmemcached is not supported on Windows, so no chances to build the memcached extension for it. However https://pecl.php.net/memcache is portable and can be used instead.

Thanks.